# Posting a Laravel form is not working

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I am setting up a simple form in laravel:

This is the route file:

```
Route::get('backoffice/upload',    [ 'as'    => 'backoffice/upload', 
                                 'uses'  => 'UploadController@uploadForm']);

Route::post('backoffice/saveimage',[ 'as'    => 'backoffice/saveimage',
                                 'uses'  => 'UploadController@saveImage']);
```

This is the controller:

```
class UploadController extends \BaseController
{

public function uploadForm()
{
return View::make("backoffice.upload.create");
}

public function saveImage()
{
return "Uploading...";
}

}
```

And this is the View file:

```
<h1>Upload Image</h1>

{{ Form::open(['action' => 'UploadController@saveImage']) }}

<div class='formfield'>
{{ Form::label('newfilename','New File Name (optional):') }}
{{ Form::input('text','newfilename') }}
{{ $errors->first('newfilename') }}
</div>

<div class='formfield'>
{{ Form::submit($action,['class'=>'button']) }}
{{ Form::btnLink('Cancel',URL::previous(),['class'=>'button']) }}
</div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

// Generated HTML

```
<h1>Upload Image</h1>

<form method="POST" action="http://my.local/backoffice/saveimage" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input     name="_token" type="hidden" value="x9g4SW2R7t9kia2B8HRJTm1jbLRl3BB8sPMwvgAM">

<div class='formfield'>
<label for="newfilename">New File Name (optional):</label>
<input name="newfilename" type="text" id="newfilename">
</div>

<div class='formfield'>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Create">
</div>

</form>
```

So, if I go to: http://my.local/backoffice/upload I get the form with the HTML above.

However, if I type anything, then click SUBMIT, I return to the form but now have the following URL:

```
http://my.local/backoffice/upload?pz_session=x9g4SW2R7t9kia2B8HRJTm1jbLRl3BB8sPMwvgAM&_token=x9g4SW2R7t9kia2B8HRJTm1jbLRl3BB8sPMwvgAM&newfilename=ddd
```

This makes no sense to me. Up until now I have always used route::resource when dealing with forms, and had no problem. I am trying to do a simple form with GET and POST and am having no end of grief. What am I missing?

Furthermore, if I modify routes.php and change it from post to any, then open a browser window and type: http://my.local/backoffice/saveimage then I get the message "Uploading..." so that part is working ok.

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution. In making the backoffice of the system, I had re-used the frontoffice template but removed all the excess. Or so I had thought. However, the front office header template had a form which I had only partially deleted.

So the problem was that there was an opening FORM tag I didn't know about. Consequently, when I clicked on submit to my form, it was actually submitting to this other form.

As the other form had no action it was default to itself.

Of course, had I just validated the HTML this would have shown up straight away. The lesson learned here is to validate my html before submitting questions!

Comment: I had a form within a form and I got this error.  So **no forms within forms!**   I was able to diagnose that thanks to your answer.

Comment: Yeah @Puzbie I'm very thankful that I found your answer after spend 6+ hours debugging all my application with no results until I find that miserable form tag opened without an action. This was causing several forms to fail in the application. I need a very cold beer right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and be sure to correctly configure your url at `app/config/app.php`

```
{{Form::open(['url'=>'backoffice/saveimage'])}}
  //code
{{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: That does the same I am afraid. Whether you use route, action or URL, the generateed HTML is the same: action="http://my.local/backoffice/saveimage"

Comment: In all cases the generated HTML is exactly what I want. However, for some reason it seems to route me back to the original form.

If however, I just type hxxp://my.local/backoffice/saveimage in the browser then I get the message I would expect to see. "Uploading..."

Comment: Try Route::GET instead of Route::POST in routes.php. I think Laravel converts all type of requests(get,delete,put) requests to post automagically.

Comment: That makes no odds. If you use ANY, which covers all bases, it still doesn't play ball.

Comment: An i think the $errors can be accessible only if you are using validations. Try commenting that out.